# Run Ansible playbook on UNIQUE user/host combination

Tags: ansible, aliases

I've been trying to implement Ansible in our team to manage different kinds of application things such as configuration files for products and applications, the distribution of maintenance scripts, ...

We don't like to work with "hostnames" in our team because we have 300+ of them with meaningless names.  Therefor, I started out creating aliases for them in the Ansible hosts file like:

```
[bpm-i]
bpm-app1-i1   ansible_user=bpmadmin  ansible_host=el1001.bc
bpm-app1-i2   ansible_user=bpmadmin  ansible_host=el1003.bc

[bpm-u]
bpm-app1-u1   ansible_user=bpmadmin  ansible_host=el2001.bc
bpm-app1-u2   ansible_user=bpmadmin  ansible_host=el2003.bc

[bpm-all:children]
bpm-i
bpm-u
```

Meaning we have a BPM application named "app1" and it's deployed on two hosts in integration-testing and on two hosts in user-acceptance-testing.  So far so good. Now I can run an Ansible playbook to (for example) setup the SSH accesses (authorized_keys) for team members or push a maintenance script.  I can run those PBs on each host seperately, on all hosts ITT or UAT or even everywhere.

But, typically, we'll have install the same application app1 again on an existing host but with a different purpose - say "training" environment. My reflex would be to do this:

```
[bpm-i]
bpm-app1-i1   ansible_user=bpmadmin  ansible_host=el1001.bc
bpm-app1-i2   ansible_user=bpmadmin  ansible_host=el1003.bc

[bpm-u]
bpm-app1-u1   ansible_user=bpmadmin  ansible_host=el2001.bc
bpm-app1-u2   ansible_user=bpmadmin  ansible_host=el2003.bc

[bpm-t]
bpm-app1-t1   ansible_user=bpmadmin  ansible_host=el2001.bc
bpm-app1-t2   ansible_user=bpmadmin  ansible_host=el2003.bc

[bpm-all:children]
bpm-i
bpm-u
bpm-t
```

But ... running PB's becomes a mess now and cause errors.  Logically I have two alias names to reach the same user/host combination : bpm-app1-u1 and bpm-app1-t1.  I don't mind, that's perfectly logical, but if I were to test a new maintenance script, I would first push it to bpm-app1-i1 for testing and when ok, I probably would run the PB against bpm-all.  But because of the non-unique user/host combinations for some aliases the PB would run multiple times on the same user/host.  Depending on the actions in the PB this may work coincidentally, but it may also fail horribly.

Is there no way to tell Ansible "Run on ALL - UNIQUE user/host combinations" ?

Comment: Comment to the above : This is a stylised example.  Changing the names of the aliases, grouping u1 and t1 (and u2 and t2) into other aliases isn't an option, only having "u" without "t" isn't an option.

The only things that matters is : Make Ansible check that it doens't run a playbook on a user/host twice when running the playbook against "all" hosts.

Comment: I did not understand why the "t" hosts need to have the same names as the "u" hosts. A hostname should be unique. But in general, I highly recommend to use different inventory files for different environments. It just is an additional precaution to protect you from accidentally playing on the wrong set of hosts. This of cause does not solve your problem, but with different host files you simply could call ansible multiple times with each inventory file separately. This then should solve your non-unique host name problem.

Comment: But be aware you can not define host_vars individually and also you will not be able to use fact caching as it would conflict between those different hosts with the same name.

Comment: They have the same names because it simply is the same host.  We typically deal with one user account managing different apps or environments on one host (product enforced) - as opposed to typical *nix sysadmins who deal with one user (superuser).
Hm.. I thought there was only one "hosts" file to rule them all, but I'll look into seperating host files.  However, it doens't solve my issue and it would become messy because in our company things get mixed up a lot (re-use of hosts for different apps/environments).
Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Since most tasks change something on the remote host, you could use [Conditionals](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html) to check for that change on the host before running.

For example, if your playbook has a task to run a script *that creates a file* on the remote host, you can add a `when` clause to "skip the task if file exists" and check for the existence of that file with a `stat` task before that one.

```
- Check whether script has run in previous instance by looking for file
  stat: path=/path/to/something
  register: something

- name: Run Script when file above does not exist
  command: bash myscript.sh
  when: not something.exists
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it could work as a work around but it means more work to be done in the playbooks of course.  You'd have to be able to define the conditions and then still be able to implement them in Ansible.  The former is of course doable in all cases, the latter is more difficult given the limitations of Ansible.
But thanks for the idea, I'll definitely look into it.